# Mysql stopped suddenly and cannot be restarted

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Here is what /var/log/mysql/error.log says

[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--mysql/'

Full log: http://pastebin.com/hhUY2LXi

Mysql config: http://pastebin.com/cNMux19T

Command to start mysql: sudo service mysql start

Any ideas or debugging steps will realy help

Comment: How are you starting the MySQL daemon?

Comment: sudo service mysql start

Comment: `sudo reboot` will solve your problem

Comment: You can't just solve every problem by rebooting it.

Comment: Tried rebooting. Didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that there was an long running process which filled up ram cache. 
I ran sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3 and i was able to restart mysql